# Is the syntax of external javascript files different from javascript?

Tags: javascript, external

If I copy the code from an external file for example to javascript lint, it keeps showing syntax errors. is the syntax different?

Comment: Please provide a better explanation so we can understand you

Comment: Lint gives a lot of output on scripts which relate to adhering to certain coding standards and styles, but this does not necessarily mean there is a syntax error.

Comment: Could you *at least* tell what errors it shows.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. The only difference is that you don't need `<script>` tags in the external js files.

Comment: You don't need them in javascript lint either, do you?